# Does Limited Magic Immunity protect against a Wand of Fear's command effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, immunities

The monster to potentially be targeted with a [*Wand of Fear*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wand%20of%20Fear#content), has the *Limited Magic Immunity* feature, which reads as follows:

> **Limited Magic Immunity**. Unless it wishes to be affected, this creature is immune to spells of 6th level or lower. It has advantage
> on saving throws against all other spells and magical effects.

What's tripping me up is the *Wand of Fear's* first effect, which reads as follows:

> **Command**: While holding the wand, you can use an action to expend 1 charge and command another creature to flee or grovel, as with the
> *command* spell (save DC 15).

It does not say it **casts the command spell**, like many other wands explicitly state that they have you cast a spell from them, but instead that it's **as with** the spell. Since *Limited Magic Immunity* explicitly only makes immune to spells, will that creature be affected by the command effect of the wand, or would it be immune?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No spell is cast if an item doesn't say so

There are items that let you cast spells and they will clearly state as much. The *Wand of Fear* doesn't say that a spell is cast, so there isn't one. The expression *as with* is used so an extensive explanation does not have to be repeated when the spell effect has the desired properties for the item's effect.

#### Advantage against magical effects applies

Notice, however, that the *Wand of Fear* is a magic item and therefore has a magical effect. The second clause of the feature granting advantage therefore still applies.